# Import of Open Sans Font in matplotlibrc Ubuntu fails

Tags: python, ubuntu, fonts, matplotlib

I try to import the Font [Open Sans](http://www.opensans.com) over:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
#update matplotlibrc
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Open Sans'

#testplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.title('Everything is crazy!!!', size=32)
plt.show()
```

If I want to plot, the font can't be found by matplotlib, giving an error message like:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1236: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Open Sans'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
      (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1246: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=light:stretch=normal:size=medium. Returning /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/cmb10.ttf
      UserWarning)
```

The font is installed in Ubuntu and all the OpenSans-*.ttf Files are also copied to the matplotlib folder (/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/ in Ubuntu).
Any Idea how to use the font in the matplotlibrc?

Comment: is the font present in one of the following directories:

    /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TTF/
    /usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts
    /usr/share/fonts/
    /usr/local/share/fonts/
    /usr/lib/openoffice/share/fonts/truetype/

Comment: I copied it to /usr/share/fonts/truetype nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is an old question but I've just installed Open Sans for use in Matplotlib too:

The OP has followed the correct steps, except needs to force the Matplotlib font cache to rebuild. The easiest way of doing this:

```
from matplotlib import font_manager
font_manager._rebuild()
```

Note than on Linux, as well as the Font paths discussed above Matplotlib appears to also search in ~/.fonts, so you can install fonts there.